# How to open another app in a popup/window?

Tags: java, android

I'm opening another app from my app using this code:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://url_to_app's_website");
Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
in.setPackage("com.package.address");

try {
    startActivity(in);

} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
    Uri.parse("http://url_to_app's_website")));
}
```

This is working but it opens the app with full screen. I want to open it in a window/popup. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be just opening a web app. If that is the case, you should do the following:

- Create a dialog with `WebView`
- Show the dialog
- Load the url in the dialog's `webView`

Refer to [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7527568/how-to-load-web-view-in-dialoge-in-android) which provides a means to do that.

Here is the code that will get you what you want:
*(borrowed from the answer to the question referenced above)*

**Dialog Layout :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Load your url in the Dialog's webView:**

```
final TextView seeMonthlyBill = (TextView) parentLayout
            .findViewById(R.id.my_ac_my_service_timewarnercable_link);
    seeMonthlyBill.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.web_dialog)
            WebView wb = (WebView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.webview);
            wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            wb.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
            wb.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            dialog.setTitle("WebView");
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: The web opens ONLY when the app/package "com.package.address" does not exist in the phone. I need the app to open in a window/popup, not the web view.

Comment: For that refer the answer by @CommonsWare

Answer (score 1):

On Android N, *if* the user has put the device into a multi-window mode, you can [use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCH_ADJACENT`](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/multi-window.html#launch) to try to launch the other activity into a separate window. However, you cannot guarantee this will work, as the other app's developers have to agree.

Prior to Android N, you cannot open another application into any sort of popup, unless that application has some specific API for that.

Answer (score 0):

The destination activity should support popup mode and if it is supported you should put the setting into a Bundle Object and pass it to Intent and then startActivity();